# Split and append to 2 arrays from input

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, split

I want something like this. String -> split -> append each without creating new 2 variables(or 1 list)

```
a=[]
b=[]
sum = 0;

for i in range(n):
    map(lambda x, y: a.append(x),b.append(y),raw_input().split(" "));
```

Yeah,thats doesn't work couse append return null. 
But that's so ugly.x

```
for i in range(n):
    buf = map(int,raw_input().split(" "));
    a.append(buf[0])
    b.append(buf[1])
```

Comment: Can you add any sample O/P you want ?

Comment: So your second piece of code already works? consider posting to [codereview.se], but remember to read their help center before asking.

Comment: (besides, I don't see how the second code is "ugly", that is good, unless you 're asking for one-liner code, then my advice: Don't.)

Comment: The first snippet is *much* uglier than the 2nd one. 1) You're doing too much in a single line; your code is too hard to read 2) It doesn't even work; it throws a `name y is not defined` exception, which should make it obvious that your code is too hard to read and should be split into multiple lines. 3) Using `map` for side effects like appending to lists is abuse of the `map` function and should be avoided. 4) Neither of the two snippets works in python 3, but the 2nd one is easier to fix.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I suppose OP is asking for Python 2. In that case  please use [tag:python-2.7] too.

Comment: @user202729 Why write python2-only code in 2018 when you can easily write code that's compatible with both versions?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I don't know, ask the OP. Probably to be golfier?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the second approach. In fact it is quite clear what it does. You could use tuple-unpacking to make it look a little nicer:

```
for i in range(n):
    first, second = map(int, raw_input().split(" "));
    a.append(first)
    b.append(second)
```

If you still wish to do it as a one-liner, here's a sample approach you could take with a different example:

```
t = ['A B', 'C D', 'E F']
a, b = zip(*(i.split() for i in t))

>>> print(a)
('A', 'C', 'E')
>>> print(b)
('B', 'D', 'F')
```